# Vectorization in Numpy - Broadcasting

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a code in python with the following elements:

I have an `intensities` vector which is something like this:

```
array([ 1142.,  1192.,  1048., ...,    29.,    18.,    35.])
```

I have also an `x` vector which looks like this:

```
array([   0,    1,    1, ..., 1060, 1060, 1061])
```

Then, I have the for loop where I fill another vector, `radialDistribution` like this:

```
for i in range(1000):
    radialDistribution[i] = sum(intensities[np.where(x == i)]) / len(np.where(x == i)[0])
```

The problem is that it takes 20 second to complete it...therefore I want to vectorize it. But I am quite new with broadcasting in Numpy and didn't find so much out there...therefore I need your help.

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
i= np.ogrid[:1000]
intensities[i] = sum(sortedIntensities1D[np.where(sortedDists1D == i)]) / len(np.where(sortedDists1D == i)[0])
```

**Could you help me just telling me where should I look to learn the vectorization procedures with Numpy?**

Thanks in advance for your valuable help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261126/array-reshaped-according-to-keys is a similar problem.  It wants to collect the values into columns, but it would be even easier to take their `mean()`.  Note the accepted answer uses `pandas.groupby`.

Comment: Be careful about using `sum` with numpy arrays.  Use `numpy.sum` or `arr.sum()` instead.  Also, don't do `arr[np.where(x == i)]`. Instead, just index with the boolean array directly: `arr[x == i]`.  It's probably (?) those two that are slowing you down (mostly `sum` vs `numpy.sum`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `x` vector has consecutive integers starting at 0, then you can simply do:

```
radialDistribution = np.bincount(x, weights=intensities) / np.bincount(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://pastebin.com/c5WLWPbp) is my implementation of group_by functionality in numpy. It is conceptually similar to the pandas solution; except that this does not require pandas, and ought to become a part of the numpy core, in my opinion.

Using this functionality, your code would look like this:

```
radialDistribution = group_by(x).mean(intensities)
```

and would complete in notime.

Look also at the test_radial function defined at the end, which may come even closer to your endgoal.

Comment: Guarding the last `d=test_mesh()` would make your `group_by` importable.

Comment: ah yes; disclaimer: this is a draft, and hasn't been reviewed by anyone other than me yet. It should work as indicated, but indeed its not a polished package. I should work it into a formal numpy PR once I find the time.

Comment: note that this solution works for any sortable vector x; it does not need to be an array of ints, for instance. Also, you can efficiently get additional stats, like group_by.std/median

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that uses broadcasting:

```
# arrays need to be at least 2D for broadcasting
x = np.atleast_2d(x)

# create vector of indices
i = np.atleast_2d(np.arange(x.size))

# do the vectorized calculation
bool_eq = (x == i.T)
totals = np.sum(np.where(bool_eq, intensities, 0), axis=1)
rD = totals / np.sum(bool_eq, axis=1)
```

This uses broadcasting two times: in the operation `x == i.T` and in the call to `np.where`. Unfortunately the code above is very slow, even slower than the original. The main bottleneck here is `np.where`, which we can speed up in this case by taking the product of the Boolean array and the intensities (also by broadcasting):

```
totals = np.sum(bool_eq*intensities, axis=1)
```

And this is essentially the same as a matrix-vector product, so we can write:

```
totals = np.dot(intensities, bool_eq.T)
```

The end result is a faster code than the original (at least until the memory use for the intermediary array becomes the limiting factor), but you're probably better off with an iterative approach, as suggested by one of the other answers.

*Edit:* making use of `np.einsum` was faster still (in my trial):

```
totals = np.einsum('ij,j', bool_eq, intensities)
```

Comment: `bool_eq = (x == np.arange(x.size)[:,None])` takes the automatic broadcasting a step further.

Comment: As with the `bincount` solution, this may need filtering where `i` values are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Building on my `itertools.groupby` solution in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22265803/901925 here's a solution that works on 2 small arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
intensities = np.arange(12,dtype=float)
x=np.array([1,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,0]) # general, not sorted or consecutive
```

first a bincount solution, adjusted for nonconsecutive values

```
# using bincount
# if 'x' are not consecutive
J=np.bincount(x)>0
print np.bincount(x,weights=intensities)[J]/np.bincount(x)[J]
```

Now a `groupby` solution

```
# using groupby;
# sort if need
I=np.argsort(x)
x=x[I]
intensities=intensities[I]

# make a record array for use by groupby
xi=np.zeros(shape=x.shape, dtype=[('intensities',float),('x',int)])
xi['intensities']=intensities
xi['x']=x

g=itertools.groupby(xi, lambda z:z['x'])
xx=np.array([np.array([z[0] for z in y[1]]).mean() for y in g])
print xx
```

Here's a compact `numpy` solution, using the `return_index` option of `np.unique`, and `np.split`.  `x` should be sorted.  I'm not optimistic about the speed for large arrays, since there will be iteration in `unique` and `split` in addition to the comprehension.

```
[values, index] = np.unique(x, return_index=True)
[y.mean() for y in np.split(intensities, index[1:])]
```

Comment: For a generic `i`, doing `i_unq, i_idx = np.unique(i, return_inverse=True)` and then calling `np.bincount(i_idx, weights=x) / np.bincount(i_idx)` would be the way to have a robust implementation that doesn't blow up regardless of the values in `i`.